# How can define constant?

Tags: php, codeception

I would like define constant with two or more parametrs.
For example:

```
const SUBMIT_BTN =  "button[type=submit], button[value=Login]";
```

Possible?

Comment: nope (well, maybe you can), that kinda goes against the principle of these kinda definitions..

Comment: Is that `PHP` tags a bit misleading here??

Comment: But anyway, as you appear to be setting a constant to a string, whats the issue ??

Comment: What is your desired result? an array?

Comment: It doesn't look like Codeception question to me either.

Answer (score 0):

I solved.

```
const SUBMIT_BTN =  "button[type=submit][value=Login]";
```